# checking for an optional UserDefaults.standard.value

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I check if I have user's Facebook data as UserDefaults.standard.value

```
if let facebookDetails:Dictionary = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "facebookDetails") as? [String:Any])! {
        dump(facebookDetails)

        let picture:Dictionary = (facebookDetails["picture"]  as? [String:Any])!
        let fb_pic_data:Dictionary = (picture["data"]  as? [String:Any])!
        let fb_pic_data_url:String = fb_pic_data["url"] as! String
            if let checkedUrl = URL(string: fb_pic_data_url) {
                profiler.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                downloadImage(url: checkedUrl)
                profiler.layer.borderWidth = 1
                profiler.layer.masksToBounds = false
                profiler.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                profiler.layer.cornerRadius = profiler.frame.height/2
                profiler.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
```

I get the following alert:
Non-optional expression of type '[String: Any]' used in a check for optionals

and app crashes if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "facebookDetails") is unset.

What is the correct way of writing this conditional if?

Thanks

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` to get an object from `UserDefaults`. Use the `object(forKey:)` method or one of the many type specific methods such as `dictionary(forKey:)` or `string(forKey:)`, etc.

Comment: and drop that exclamation mark at the end of the expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are completely misusing optionals, forced-unwrapping, and `if let`.

You should also avoid using `value(forKey:)`. And avoid needless type declarations. Let Swift infer the type when appropriate.

Your `if` should be:

```
if let facebookDetails = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "facebookDetails") {
}
```

You should also avoid the force-unwrapping unless you know for sure that the value (or cast) will always succeed.

And be consistent in your code. On one line you do:

```
let picture:Dictionary = (facebookDetails["picture"]  as? [String:Any])!
```

and another you do:

```
let fb_pic_data_url:String = fb_pic_data["url"] as! String
```

Why take two different approaches to forcing the case and the optional?